# How to reconcile two different expressions for the Noether current?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, gauge-theory, noethers-theorem

In *A Modern Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* by Maggiore (as well as in my quantum field theory course), the Noether current for an internal symmetry is found to be

$$j^{\mu}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu} \phi)}\delta\phi\tag{3.32}$$

where the fields transform as $\phi\rightarrow\phi+\alpha\delta\phi$ for infinitesimal $\alpha$ (and the coordinates are unchanged). However, in *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* by Peskin and Schroeder, if the Lagrangian transforms as $$\mathcal{L}\rightarrow\mathcal{L}+\alpha\partial_{\mu}\mathcal{J}^{\mu},\tag{2.10}$$ it is given in general by

$$j^{\mu}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu} \phi)}\delta\phi-\mathcal{J}^{\mu},\tag{2.12}$$

which is clearly not the same. Initially I thought that $\mathcal{J}^{\mu}=0$ for an internal symmetry so that they would match. However, answers on [my last question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/700626/) have shown that this is not true. **Both books assume the action is invariant, not necessarily the Lagrangian.** So, what is going on here?

Comment: Maggiore is just starting with a special case. And of course, there are version of Noether's theorem even more general than Peskin's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, Peskin & Schroeder between eqs. (2.9) & (2.10) assume that the infinitesimal transformation is a [quasi-symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) of the action, i.e. the action can change by a boundary term; while Maggiore below eq. (3.20) assumes a strict symmetry of the action.
2. Correspondingly, the [Noether current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) gets modified with an improvement term in Peskin & Schroeder's eq. (2.12) as compared to Maggiore's eq. (3.32).
3. Btw, both Noether currents (2.12) & (3.32) assume so-called vertical transformations, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301847/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: But Maggiore also assumes a quasi-symmetry, i.e. that the action is invariant but not necessarily the Lagrangian.

Comment: That's not the definition of a quasi-symmetry of the action.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the boundary term vanishes for some reason